# Python dataframe value insertion to database table column

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to insert python dataframe values to database table column?

I am using snowflake as my database.

CommuteTime is the table which contains the StudentID column. "add_col" is the python dataframe. I need to insert the df values to StudentID column.

Below is my code which i have tried to insert df values to table column.

```
c_col = pd.read_sql_query('insert into "SIS_WIDE"."PUBLIC"."CommuteTime" ("StudentID") VALUES ("add_col")', engine)
```

When I execute the above its not accepting the dataframe. Its throwing the below error.

```
ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 68
invalid identifier '"add_col"' [SQL: 'insert into "SIS_WIDE"."PUBLIC"."CommuteTime" ("StudentID") VALUES ("add_col")'] 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Please provide suggestions to fix this..

Comment: Certainly not by using `pd.read_sql_query`. That is for creating a dataframe from the result of a SELECT statement. There is a [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method on dataframes, but that will (try to) insert the dataframe as a table. If you really wich to insert the whole dataframe as a single attribute on a single record as your query suggests, you'll have to do that manually.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make it with `pd.read_sql_query`.

First, you need to create [Snowflake cursor](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html).

e.g.

```
import snowflake.connector

cursor = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='username',
password='password',
database='database_name',
schema='PUBLIC',
warehouse='warehouse_name'
).cursor()
```

Once you have a cursor, you can query like this: `cursor.execute("SELECT * from "CommuteTime")`

To insert data into tables, you need to use [INSERT INTO from Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/insert.html)

Please provide more info about your dataframe, to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to do that using **SQL Alchemy**, not Snowflake Python Connector.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Establish the connection to the Snowflake database
sf = 'snowflake://{}:{}@{}{}'.format(user, password, account, table_location)
engine = create_engine(sf)
# Write your data frame to a table in database 
add_col.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

See [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#connection-string-examples) to learn how to establish a connection to Snowflake by passing `username`, `password`, `account`, and `table location`.

Explore [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to learn about the arguments you can pass as `if_exists` to the function `to_sql()`.